# Removing/Turning off the ORCID ID feature in els-cas template

Tags: footnotes, titles, els-cas

Is there a way to remove/turn off the ORCID ID feature from the footnote of the title page? I am using Elsevier's CAS LaTeX Single Column Template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please show us a small compilable example of your document?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the `ORCID(s):` footnote like at the bottom of this page (which is a rather odd default, since no ORCID was actually given):

> [image]

then the only way to remove it seems to be by un-defining the command `\printorcid` (with `\let\printorcid\relax`, for example):

```latex
\documentclass{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\let\printorcid\relax % Remove ORCID footnote
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

then the output looks like:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issues :-)